# Phoenix (elixir) channel usage with WebSocket (js)

Tags: websocket, phoenix-framework

After 1 day of full search, I didn't find a way on how to send events to a Phoenix channel via the [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) javascript class.

This is my channel definition :

```
defmodule Test.GeneralRoomChannel do
  use Test.Web, :channel

  # Rejoins la room générale
  def join("general_room:lobby", payload, socket) do
    if authorized?(payload) do
      {:ok, socket}
    else
      {:error, %{reason: "unauthorized"}}
    end
  end

  def handle_in("send_msg", payload, socket) do
    broadcast! socket, "send_msg", payload
    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  # Add authorization logic here as required.
  defp authorized?(_payload) do
    true
  end
end
```

I have this to connect to join channel

```
this.ws = new WebSocket('ws://x.x.x.x:4000/socket/websocket');

this.ws.onopen = () => {
  this.ws.send(JSON.stringify({
    "topic": "general_room:lobby",
    "event": "phx_join",
    "payload": {"username": "Peekmo"},
    "ref": "lfskj"
  }));
};
```

It works for "join" event, but I don't know how to send the "send_msg" event. When I do this :

```
this.ws.send(JSON.stringify({
  "topic": "general_room:lobby",
  "event": "send_msg",
  "payload": {"body": this.state.text},
  "ref": "sdkfml"
}));
```

no function clause matching in Test.GeneralRoomChannel.handle_in/3

I don't understand why, and as I am not very comfortable with websockets, I'm a bit lost.

Comment: I have tried to answer as far as I could given your post... Please try to paste here the exact error that elixir gives you, so we can further investigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce your issue...I couldn't, it works fine.

You can try to debug yourself the code by adding :

```
def handle_in("send_msg", payload, socket) do
  broadcast! socket, "send_msg", payload
  {:noreply, socket}
end
def handle_in(event, payloas, socket) do
  IO.puts("Other event: #{event}")
  {:noreply, socket}
end
```

IMHO, you probably have a special character in the string "send_msg" that prevent pattern matching in the server side. (Thats the kind of things you can't see, but mess up your code)

Further more, you should not try to recreate the wheel since Phoenix gives you a full set of functions to handle Channels without having to code everything with raw Websockets. Since you are not (in your words) confortable with WebSockets, you should check it out.

[Phoenix Channels](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/channels)

Comment: I used the 'phoenix-socket' npm package finally, but I didn't really successfully found a way to use WebSocket class. It was probably an other error somewhere else.. Perhaps a closed connection ? I will never know^^

Comment: Your way was correct,I copy/paste your code into a new project to test it out, it worked first try... Like I said probably a hidden character somewhere messing with pattern matching